# Copy Label from GroupBox to another GroupBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm going **to copy** all Labels from a GroupBox to another GroupBox. Here is the code:

```
        foreach (var ctrl in grpA.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(Label))
            {
                Label lbl = ctrl as Label;
                grpB.Controls.Add(lbl);
            }
        }
```

The problem is that all Labels **are moved** to grpB where as I need to be copied. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Create a new label and assign the text to the original label's text? `grpB.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = lbl.Text })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating new `Label` for each `Label` in  other group.

```
    foreach (var ctrl in grpA.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(Label))
        {
            Label lbl = ctrl as Label;
            Label b = new Label();
            // copy required properties
            b.Text = lbl.Text
            b.TextAlign = lbl.TextAlign;
            // ... other properties

            grpB.Controls.Add(b);
        }
    }
```